# fit-content on parent but child have 100% height html, css

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrapper {
  max-height: 200px;
  height: fit-content;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.header{
  height: 20px;
}

.main{
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content{
  height: 1000px;
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='header'></div>
  <div class='main'>
    <div class='content'></div
  <div>
</div
```

I have a `wrapper` div, which have `height: fit-content`.

I want when `content` have high `height`, the main will `scroll`. But it not work.

The conflict is: `wrapper`: `height: fit-content`, but the `.main` height depend on `100%`. But i can't find out some solution.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  max-height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #f00; /* Added just for visualization */
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  min-height: 1000px;
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='header'></div>
  <div class='main'>
    <div class='content'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```